# How to configure a deserializer securizer with graniteds?

Tags: java, apache-flex, amf, graniteds

In the latest version of granite ds, the deserializer securizer has been introduced.

If I understand well, this is basically to prevent the deserializer to invoke classes that were not meant to be transported.

Unfortunately I cannot find how to configure it in the `granite-config.xml`. And this part is not very well documented nor in the documentation nor in the Javadoc of the `RegexAMF3DeserializerSecurizer`.

Does anyone have the xml snippet to add?

Thanks in advance
M.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spot the answer.

```
<amf3-deserializer-securizer param="org\.granite\..* | flex\.messaging\..* | my\.packages\.bo\..*"/>
```

This will configure the default securizer and allows it to construct classes from the specified packages.

M.